# Integration Wildfly appication server and Websphere MQ

Tags: jms, integration, wildfly, ibm-mq

I need to integrate Wildfly and Websphere MQ it means that I want send JMS message from Wildfly to Websphere MQ. 
What is the best way to achieve this? Should I implement some client and sent these JMS messages directly or maybe there is similar method like JMS bridge?

Comment: Try reviewing some other SO posts related to the same subject.  Come back with more detailed questions if you have it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wildfly+ibm-mq?sort=active

Comment: Sorry for too generic question but I only know that machine with Websphere will be reachable through a Netscaler, using the AMQP protocol.I can sse that people use Resource Adapter from IBM but I have to use AMPQ, so in this case probably Resource Adapter will not be useful.

Comment: I would use [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/amqp.html) for this

Comment: Note that it is no longer called Websphere MQ as of v8 which is when they added AMQP support, IBM just markets it as IBM MQ now.You would not need the IBM MQ Resource Adapter to connect to AMQP, the RA does not include a AMQP client.  Any AMQP client that meets the standard that IBM implemented can connect.  If you are looking for more info you can google the term MQLight which is what IBM refers to the AMQP support as.